# Unit Testing ASP.NET MVC Project that Has a Database Connection String Defined in Web.Configuration.WebconfigurationManager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have an ASP.NET MVC project that I would like to unit test.  Most of the functions rely on a call to our database, who's connection string is defined as:

```
connStr.ProviderConnectionString = Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ApplicationServices").ConnectionString
```

Is there some way to easily test this without making each unit test fire off the dev server with:

```
 <TestMethod(), _
 HostType("ASP.NET"), _
 AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("C:\Users\tyler.HQ\Development\LateralSports\Dev\Dev\Site", "/"), _
 UrlToTest("http://localhost:57110/")> _
```

Using the `HostType` allows the unit tests to run, but it is super slow.

Is there some configuration parameter I can swap around?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should find a better way to get at the connection string. Options include:

- Use the normal System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager rather than whatever that thing is.
- Use dependency injection to abstract it away.
- Avoid the DB in unit tests entirely -- it is a bit of an infrastructure concern after all.

Comment: I'm intrigued by your last point.  How are we supposed to check if data is persisted correctly if we don't test the DB? I convert most of my Entity objects to custom types (I only need pieces of the Entity object) when showing it to the user. I need to make sure my custom types correctly get mapped back to Entity types.  I'm new to this, so I'm sure I'm doing something strangely.

Comment: So confirm that they get mapped back correctly. Let the guys responsible for the EF make sure they write to the database correctly.

Comment: +1. See also the [Repository Pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx).

Comment: Gotchya.  We are a small shop.  I'm now responsible for the EF as well.  Somebody else did all the configuration, so I was really confused.  I'll check out your ideas.  Thanks!

Comment: Gotcha. By "guys responsible for the EF" I mean the ADO.NET team at Microsoft, not your small shop :)